# Using callback once the angular bootstrap typeahead is loaded and rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html code

```
<div id="myQuestion" class="col-sm-9" style="overflow-y: auto;height: 100%;">
    <span>
        <input type="text" style="overflow:auto" ng-model="selected" 
             typeahead="item for item in filterInput($viewValue) |   limitTo:10"
             typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item)'>                                                                     
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to have a callback function once the typeahead is filtered and rendered to ui, something like an afterrender event. I am using angular bootstrap typeahead. How can I achieve this?

Comment: after rendering or after user selects it?

Comment: After rendering. Before user selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback to check when the `typeahead` is `rendered`.
But you can use the `viewContentLoaded` event for this.

In your controller listen for this event:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //do your stuff here
}
```